# Fetching external pages using capybara poltergeist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, poltergeist

I have a rails application with a bunch of integration tests running with the capybara driver poltergeist. They are all running great.

I have one test however where I need to hit an external url for example http://www.google.com - I cant get this to work, it always just loads the local app.

If I for example do the following:

```
visit "http://google.com"
page.html
```

It outputs the html of the front page of my rails app rather than the html of google.com

Has anyone gotten remote urls to work with poltergeist alongside local tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that my tests were actually using the default driver and poltergeist is only used if you manually switch over to using the js driver. The rack driver cant access external urls, so you need to make sure you switch over to the js driver. Therefore to fix the above you simply have to do:

```
Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver
visit "http://google.com"
page.html
```

Also for others with the same problem its worth checking out https://gist.github.com/turadg/5399790

Comment: As an alternative, a very common solution is to tag the tests requiring the js driver with :js => true.  For example RSpec.feature 'User sign-up', js: true do

Comment: True, but in my case I am using minitest not rspec.